# NoReverseMatch at /invoicing/search/

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-urls

At localhost when i search for example number of invoicing I have "Server Error (500)":
[image]

We have the supplier and the invoice, each supplier has 1+ invoices, when i go search the supplier for invoicing, i have this error

> NoReverseMatch at /invoicing/search/
> Reverse for 'profilePage' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['accounts/profile/(?P[0-9]+)$']"

Can you help me to fixed this?

Comment: Please don't post code or error messages as an image, include it as formatted test in your question instead. The chained lookup you pass in the url tag is resolving to None at some point, you'll need to debug where - `invoice.records.last.user.pk`

Comment: Show your urls.py with `profilePage` pattern and template or view which tries to build this url. As text, not screenshot of text please.

Comment: Hello Ivan this is the URL code.  path('profile/<int:pk>', views.ProfileView, name = 'profilePage'),